# How to solve runing error in Groovy Script

Tags: testing, soapui, web-api-testing

I have tried to get the property value, where I have saved in the project-properties.

This is the code which I have tried out.`log.info` wasn't working fine ,but when I run the code separately(that means only first line..), It shows the valid answer in a popup.

```
def ProjectProp = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Name")

log.info {"Project Property = "+ProjectProp}
```

I am new to SoapUI.I would be really grateful, If you will be able to help me out to find a solution for the error which i received as follows,

> INFO:Script13$_run_closure1@1d32637

Comment: you may try without {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is unrelated to SoapUI. You obviously have difficulty with basic Groovy syntax. Seek some tutorial on Groovy.

Your specific case, should read:

```
def projectProp = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Name")
log.info("Project Property = " + $projectProp)
```

Comment: Thanku so much,Still I'm new to SoapUI.